# Pass to the method as parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method with a lot of code

```
public function createNewObject(Request $request) 
{
  // Code...
}
```

There is another method that I plan to call, but how to pass it to the `createNewObject` method as a `Request` argument?

```
public function deleteAndCreateObject() 
{
  $this->createNewObject(???);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type-hint it in your `deleteAndCreateObject()` method.

```php
class YourController
{
    public function createNewObject(Request $request) 
    {
        // Code...
    }

    public function deleteAndCreateObject(Request $request) 
    {
        $this->createNewObject($request);
    }
}
```

If that—for some reason—doesn't work for you, you can always use [`request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request):

```php
class YourController
{
    public function createNewObject() 
    {
        $request = request();
        // Code...
    }

    public function deleteAndCreateObject() 
    {
        $this->createNewObject();
    }
}
```